# Using group_by and summarise from dplyr for all rows not containing the variable to group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame with such as

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 
                  cost = c(100, 10, 120, 102, 102)
```

I know that I can use

```
df1.a <- group_by(df1, id) %>%
    summarise(no.c = n(), 
              m.costs = mean(cost))
```

to calculate the number of observations and mean by id. How could I do so if I want to calculate the number of observations and mean for all rows that are NOT equal to the ID, so it would for example give me 3 as value for observations not A and 2 for observations not B.

I would like to use the dplyr package and the group_by functions since I have to this for a lot of huge dataframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.` to refer to the whole data.frame, which lets you calculate the differences between the group and the whole:

```
df1 %>% group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(n = n(), 
              n_other = nrow(.) - n, 
              mean_cost = mean(cost), 
              mean_other = (sum(.$cost) - sum(cost)) / n_other)

## # A tibble: 2 × 5
##       id     n n_other mean_cost mean_other
##   <fctr> <int>   <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>
## 1      A     2       3        55        108
## 2      B     3       2       108         55
```

As you can see from the results, with two groups you could just use `rev`, but this approach will scale to more groups or calculations easily.

Comment: This is great thank you. It works, but when I try something like this 
`df1.a <- group_by(df1, id) %>% 
  summarise(nrow_other = nrow(.[!.$id == id, ]))` 
then it works, but returns me the warning:
 `In `==.default`(.$id, c(2L, 2L, 2L)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`. 
Could you maybe outline what my error is? Your solution for the number of rows work, but I would like to subset in the summarise function for all rows that do not contain the variable that was grouped_by. Thank you!

Comment: `id` and `.$id` are not the same length nor length 1, so when you compare them, `==` is using vector recycling to make `id` the right length. Since it's all one value it's fine, but wrap it in `unique` to make it go away or use the approach above.

Comment: Ok, awesome thank you. could you maybe be so kind to outline your hint about `unique` in more detail? If possible, with an example.

Comment: `summarise(nrow_other = nrow(.[.$id != unique(id), ]))`. Yet another alternative would be `summarise(nrow_other = sum(.$id != unique(id)))`, though I'd still stick with `summarise(nrow_other = nrow(.) - n())` as long as it's grouped by `id` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for something like this? This calculates the total cost and total number of rows firstly and then subtract the total cost and total number of rows for each group and take average for the cost:

```
sumCost = sum(df1$cost)
totRows = nrow(df1)

df1 %>% 
        group_by(id) %>% 
        summarise(no.c = totRows - n(), 
                  m.costs = (sumCost - sum(cost))/no.c)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#      id  no.c m.costs
#  <fctr> <int>   <dbl>
#1      A     3     108
#2      B     2      55
```